# Address in mailbox given [address] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: php, laravel

->When a user creates an account, a verification email sent to him. This is my goal.
     ->I am working with Laravel and I am new begginer.
    ->I set correctly the STMP details that is needed as password, username, port, encryption
    ->I hope I was clear.
->At email.php the from is:  'from' => [
       'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],

So my codes are:

verifyController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class VerifyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * verify the user with a given token
     * 
     * 
     */
    public function verify($token)
    {
        User::where('token', $token)->firstOrFail();

            $this->update(['token' => null]); //verify the user


            return redirect('/profile');

            $this->route('home')
            ->with('success', 'Account verifed');

    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use App\Notifications\VerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'password', 'token'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function orders(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order');

    }
    /**
     * Returns true if user is verified
     * @return bool
     * 
     */


    public function verified()
    {
        return $this->token === null;
    }

    /**
     * Send the user a verification user
     * @return void
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * */


    public function sendVerificationEmail()
    {
        $this->notify(new VerifyEmail($this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days and hours I realized that versions of Laravel Frameworks have differences. So the problem was that I had input port: 465, host: smtp.gmail.com, Username and password of Application that Google gives you and at .env file, mail.php, ***also*** in config\config.php. ! I hope am helping future questions about it.